# Why I'm getting error while calculating seasonal observation from daily time series data?

Tags: r

Hello everyone,

Hope you all are doing well. I'm facing a problem while trying to calculate seasonal observation (using the `dm2seasonal` function from the `hydroTSM` package in Rstudio) from daily time-series data (1951-2020).
The error occurred, especially when calculating the Winter Season (comprising of December, January, and February). The error is as follows.

```
Error in 1:(nrow(s.a) - 1) : argument of length 0
```

A subset of the raw data I'm using to calculate seasonal observation:

```
Date        ETO
01-01-1951  2.53
02-01-1951  2.95
03-01-1951  2.99
04-01-1951  2.71
05-01-1951  2.74
06-01-1951  3.02
.
.
.
27-12-2020  2.73
28-12-2020  2.57
29-12-2020  2.86
30-12-2020  2.96
31-12-2020  3.11
```

I'm completely confused and looking for a suitable solution or any alternatives to do the task. Thank you.

Comment: Is the variable `s.a` yours or somewhere within one of the packages' functions? If it's not yours, then this is likely either you forgetting an argument or passing it a `NULL` instead of a frame. It's impossible for us to know for sure since we don't have your code, but that's where I'd start. (FYI, if it is your code, `1:(nrow(s.a)-1)` is not good practice, I recommend `seq_len(max(0,nrow(s.a)-1))`.)

Comment: No. s.a is not the variable. It's the error message. Here is the actual code
#Reading excel file
`install.packages(readxl)  
library(readxl)  
X<- read_excel("E:/Data/Var/ET0/ET0.xlsx", sheet = "ET1", col_names = TRUE)  
X$Date<-as.Date(X$Date)  
X<-as.data.frame(X)`  
#Calculate seasonal observations from daily data
`install.packages(hydroTSM)  
library(hydroTSM)  
Win<- dm2seasonal(X, season = "DJF", FUN = "mean", na.rm = TRUE, dates=1, date.fmt = "%Y-%m-%d", out.type = "data.frame", out.fmt="%Y")`  
While running this code I'm getting the error mentioned above

Comment: That's what I thought, `s.a` is a variable within one of the `hydroTSM` functions. I suggest you hunt down the source of each function and find where that call is, then backtrack it to your call. It might be helpful to use the github interface to look around, ala https://github.com/hzambran/hydroTSM.